# Postman showing "sending request" message but does not do anything

Tags: postman

I was using Postman on my desktop and it was working fine but suddenly after creating a new request it stopped working.

When I try to send request it just shows me sending request message but does not do anything, there is no error message.

I tried it on browser and it gave me the following error:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/api/user/all-users
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5000
Network
Request Headers
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.33.0
Accept: /
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 3212aa03-1b2b-478e-84dc-af98f8d6fa96
Host: localhost:5000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

Shown this error when trying to click on postman

Comment: You sure your backend is running? This error happens when it can't connect

Comment: The error message ECONNREFUSED means that your attempt to connect was refused by the server. In simpler terms, something at `localhost:5000` isn't accepting connections. Could you please try Curl to check `curl http://localhost:5000/api/user/all-users`. If this works then there must be some `hosts` problem. THen Ensure `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` aren't being redirected or blocked in your hosts file.